# Shift column values to the left with group constraints

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a "potentially" large DataFrame,

```
     A    B_1    B_2    B_3    C_1    C_2    C_3
0  231  text2  text3    NaN  date4  date1    NaN
1  443  NaN    NaN    text1  date2    NaN    NaN
2  456  text1  text1  text2  NaN    date3  date1
```

In order to minimize some of the `NaN`s I want to shift all the data to the left and thus be able to disregard all `NaN` columns. This shift though must remain within the appropriate group, meaning that it does not matter if a cell is in column B_1 or B_2, as long as it does not get shifted to C_1 etc.

What I want to end up with is this,

```
     A    B_1    B_2    B_3    C_1    C_2    
0  231  text2  text3    NaN  date4  date1
1  443  text1    NaN    NaN  date2    NaN
2  456  text1  text1  text2  date3  date1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [justify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52621908/2901002) function per groups, only necessary `MultiIndex` in columns:

```
df = df.set_index('A')
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(justify(x.values, invalid_val=np.nan), 
                           index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(f)
print (df)
         B                    C            
         1      2      3      1      2    3
A                                          
231  text2  text3    NaN  date4  date1  NaN
443  text1    NaN    NaN  date2    NaN  NaN
456  text1  text1  text2  date3  date1  NaN
```

And then:

```
df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

---

Combined with solution from [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57375435/2901002):

```
g = df.groupby('A').cumcount() + 1
df1 = df.set_index(['A', g]).unstack()

f = lambda x: pd.DataFrame(justify(x.values, invalid_val=np.nan), 
                           index=x.index, columns=x.columns)
df1 = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(f)

df1.columns = [f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in df1.columns]
df1 = df1.reset_index()
```

Comment: In your combined solution, what effect does `df = df.groupby(axis=1, level=0).apply(f)` have? It does not seem to be used in `df1`